# How to `$destroy` directive and replace with new values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 set of arrays. the first set is being as the default. when user click the next button, i need to update the new set. I can do this.

But the previous set as well exist. I don't know how to properly remove that, and define the new values. I am looking for the way that, which remove the `event listner` while remove the `DOM`. and memory leak should not be as well.

here is my js :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('main', function ($scope) {

  $scope.values = [{"name":"one", "num" : 1}, {"name":"two", "num" : 2}, {"name":"three", "num" : 3}];

  $scope.next = function () {
    $scope.index = 4;
    $scope.values = [{"name":"four", "num" : 4}, {"name":"five", "num" : 5}, {"name":"six", "num" : 6}];

  }

  $scope.index = 0;

  $scope.update = function (value) {
    console.log("clicked " + value.num);
    $scope.index = value.num;
    $scope.$apply();
  }

});

myApp.directive("newArray", function ($compile) {

  return {

    scope : {
      value : "=",
      index : "=",
      update:"&"
    },

    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var getTemplate = function (value, index) {

        switch(index) {

          case 0 :
            return '<div ng-click="update()">I am here {{index}} {{value.name}}</div>'
            break;

            case 1 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'blue',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.value.num});
              }
            });
            break;

            case 2 :
            return $('<div />', {
              class:'green',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.value.num});
              }
            });
            break;

        }

      }

      element.html(getTemplate(scope.value, scope.index));
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      element.replaceWith(element.contents());

    }

  }

});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtQjhEbq5TjBzqaJZXdO?p=preview)

updating my `plnkr` is appreciated. may help my future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a different requirement I'll not go for the isolated scope directive that will mess up, As you want to use replace directive DOM with the the directive template. Another reason you are using `ng-repeat` on your directive which is not maintaining DOM structure in proper manner as you are replacing directive DOM with the newly constructed DOM. Instead of which I created a simple directive that do loop inside directive and create a element with new isolated scope & appending it to Pseudo element inside watcher.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="main">
   <a ng-click="next()" href="#">Next</a>
   <h1>{{index}}</h1>
   <new-array values='values'></new-array>
</body>
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive("newArray", function ($compile) {
  return {
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var getTemplate = function (value, index) {
        var newScope = scope.$new(true);
        newScope.value = value;
        switch(index) {
          case 0 :
            newScope.index = index;
            return  $compile('<div ng-click="$parent.update(value)">I am here {{value.num}} {{value.name}}</div>')(newScope)
            break;
            case 1 :
            return $compile($('<div />', {
              class:'blue',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.values[index].num});
              }
            }))(newScope);
            break;
            case 2 :
            return $compile($('<div />', {
              class:'green',
              html : "<h1>testing{{index}} {{value.name}}</h1>",
              click : function () {
                scope.update({num: scope.values[index].num});
              }
            }))(newScope);
            break;
        }
      }
      scope.$watch('values', function(newVal){
        var html = '', dom = $('<div/>');
        element.empty();
        for(var i=0;i < newVal.length; i++){
          element.append(getTemplate(newVal[i], i))
        }
        //element.replaceWith(dom)
      }, true);
    }
  }
})
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/In7r5zp8lrYsh1sZBdgs?p=preview)

**Note**

> You can not really think of $destroy in your case. It just like
>   `destructor` which used to clear the events.

Comment: @user2024080 Glad to help you lad..That was so much challenging for me..felt like relief after solving it.Thanks .:)